# How to output all Python syntax errors in the same file?

Tags: python, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I currently have a shell script that executes a Python compiler called py_compile on all Python files that have been changed since the last Git commit. The purpose of this script is to catch all syntax errors on all changed files. The issue I am having now is that py_compile is only able to catch the first syntax error it encounters, so if there are multiple syntax errors after that, it does not indicate them. Is there a Python compiler that can display all syntax errors in a single Python file? If not, is it possible for me to write my own compiler or solution that accomplishes that?

For example, if I have the code in the attached picture, I want a solution where it can give me the "Invalid Syntax" warning at both lines 9 and 10 at once. Right now, I would have to fix the error at line 9 first before the warning for line 10 appears.[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhTBI.png)

Comment: Are you using [this py_compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html)? If so, I suggest you read the documentation of `py_compile` to find out if it has a way to do what you want.

Comment: I don't think that's possible since a syntax error means it potentially won't understand anything below that error. Think about a bracket left open. Should the closing bracket be straight after, or are you supposed to have the rest of the entire file all contained within that?